# How to make visible property work immediately in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Demo:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Component.onCompleted: {
        test.visible = true // 1. Show rect
        for(var i = 0; i < 5000000000; i++){var t = i * i} // 2. Slow process, Sleep here
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: test
        color: "red"
        width: 100; height: 100
        visible: false
    }
}
```

The visible property works when function completed. In the demo, the `test` rectangle couldn't show at the moment after `1.`, have to wait until function finished.

I understand it should cause by the process blocks rendering. But is there any trick to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heavy tasks should not be executed in the GUI thread, but in another thread so that they do not get blocked. QML offers to WorkerScript, this allows you to execute tasks in another thread:

**slow_process.js**

```
WorkerScript.onMessage = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 5000000000; i++){
        var t = i * i
        console.log(t)
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Component.onCompleted: {
        test.visible = true // 1. Show rect
        ws.sendMessage()
    }

    WorkerScript {
        id: ws
        source: "slow_process.js"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: test
        color: "red"
        width: 100; height: 100
        visible: false
    }
}
```

Comment: one more little question, I am not familiar with WorkerScript...Is it fine accessing the const data which in the main thread?  Just read only. During the script processing, I need to use some config data which expose from C++.

Comment: @Jiu 
with `sendMessage(config1, config2, ..., confign)` WorkerScript copies the values, that is, you can pass data to it. 
The best way to know is to try and read the docs :)

Comment: so I have to copy the values, directly read the property of the config object is a bad idea.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that WorkScript will copy the value as a common C ++ function does.

Comment: OK, WorkScript passes the params as value.